# Push iOS app in IBM bluemix mobilefirst foundation service and can run that app in mobile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

1. I have an ios application and I have registred my iOS application in my IBM Bluemix mobileFirst Foundation service. But if I want to make some changes in my application after making those changes, How will I push that updated iOS onto my registered MobileFirst Foundation server.
2. Second thing I wanted to know that how will I use that app to run into my mobilePhone i.e; android or apple mobile phone. Is there any way to do it using graphical interface from mobileFirst foundation console or any way so that I can test my app or can generate APK of that from there only.
3. My last question is where and how can I publish my iOS app.

I have found several links for these answers but none of them got satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I have an ios application and i have registred my ios application in my IBM bluemix mobileFirst Foundation service. But if i want to make some changes in my application after making those changes, How will i push that updated ios onto my registered MobileFirst Foundation server.

You use the MobileFirst CLI or MobileFirst Console in order to register (only *register*) the application in the MobileFirst Server's database. This has no relation what so ever to the application's web resources.

If you want to update the application you can either publish a new version to the App Store, or - in case you want to only update its HTML/CSS/JavaScript - use MobileFirst Foundation's Direct Update feature.

Learn how to use Direct Update, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/

> 2) Second thing i wanted to know that how will i use that app to run into my mobilePhone i.e; android or apple mobile phone. Is there any way to do it using graphical interface from mobileFirst foundation console or any way so that i can test my app or can generate apk of that from there only.

MobileFirst Foundation is not related to the building and running of your application or generating .apk / .ipa files.

To create native apps you use Xcode / Android Studio / Visual Studio. To these projects you add the MobileFirst SDK. You then build your project in the IDE that you use.

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/

To create Cordova (hybrid / web) apps, you use the Cordova CLI (or other tooling such as Ionic, etc...). You add the MobileFirst Cordova SDK (a Cordova plug-in). You then build your project using Cordova commands in command-line.

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/

> 3) My last question is where and how can i publish my ios app.

Please see the Apple Developer documentation regarding how to publish applications to the iOS App Store. In general you need to purchase either a developer or enterprise account and follow Apple's steps to ready your project for publication. Start here: http://developer.apple.com/

Comment: In your last answer i mean to say " how can i publish my ionic app for ios platform in IBM bluemix mobileFirst Foundation service".

Comment: You do not publish anything to the server. You only REGISTER the app so that the server will "know" the app. See my answer above.